What does it mean the "Natural language support" message at R's interactive startup?
When R starts in interactive mode a message with version, license and other information is displayed.
This message also contains the legend "Natural language support but running in an English locale".
What does it mean?

It means that if you were running in a locale where a different language (e.g. Spanish, French) was standard, R would display some of its messages in that language.  To see it, try setting the environment variable LANGUAGE to ES before starting R.  It's easiest from the command line.

Currently about 21 languages are handled.
